# Getting cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "I5": invalid identifier even though cloumn exist

Tags: sql, oracle, cx-oracle

```
c.execute('select *
           from IQMS.work_center,
                IQMS.TA_labor
           where work_center.ID = TA_labor.WORK_CENTER_ID
             and TA_labor.CUSER1 = %s'% hostname)
```

the same above command I am able to run and get the output in SQL Developer.

Please help me in this

Comment: Where exactly do you see `I5` in this query?

Comment: @jarth, while the code looks prettier after your edit, it is also broken now.

Comment: You can't run that code exactly as it in in SQL Developer. Presumably `hostname` evaluates to `I5`? If the column is a string then you need to enclose it in (escaped) quotes, e.g. as `... TA_labor.CUSER1 = \'%s\'' % hostname)`, or using double-quotes for your string literal so you don't have to escape the single quotes.  But you should be using [bind variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#bind), not embedding a string value.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I am not able to see that I5 in the query nor in the table

Comment: Also, you really should learn ANSI SQL join syntax. The syntax you are using hasn't been considered good practice for 30+ years